# Download all user profile images in Microsoft Graph using python and associate each one to the respective user on his vCard

Tags: python, curl, microsoft-graph-api, addressbook, vcf-vcard

I need to download all the user profile images on Microsoft Graph via Python and then, in order to complete the vCard, take each downloaded image and associate it with the respective user.

```
import requests

url="https:\\microsoft url token"
data = {
    "accept": 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    "Content-Type": 'xxxx',
    "grant_type": 'xxxx',
    "client_id": "xxxx",
    'scope':'graph microsoft, this is an https address',
    "client_secret": "xxxx",
}
response=requests.post(url, data=data)
```

I receive an http 402 error and so i don't finally know how to retrieve the users profile image that I need

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: first check `print( response.text )` - maybe there is some information about problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL is not valid.

To get data you may need to use a GET `requests.get()`

This is what MS recommends:

```
Method  Description
GET     Read data from a resource.
POST    Create a new resource, or perform an action.
PATCH   Update a resource with new values.
PUT     Replace a resource with a new one.
DELETE  Remove a resource.
```

**If you can point me to the documentation or source where you got your code, I may be able to help.** 
.

I am guessing you may want something like this:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'client_secret': 'xxxx',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'grant_type': 'xxxx',
    'scope': 'graph microsoft, this is an https address',
    'client_secret': 'xxxx',
}
response = requests.get('https://microsoft.com', headers=headers)
```

.

Comment: Many thanks @Misunderstood. I have another problem:
When I try to make a request.get (url, token) to retrieve the image associated with each user, I get this error message:

{'error': {'code': 'ImageNotFound', 'message': "Exception of type 'Microsoft.Fast.Profile.Core.Exception.ImageNotFoundException' was thrown."

Comment: @RRM I'm sorry I am not familiar with this API at all.  I am pretty good with curl.  I would guess that profiles does not have an image.  Google the error.  I found this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67890426/microsoft-graph-user-photo-microsoft-fast-profile-core-exception-imagenotfou   If I helped you, give my answer a check

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion, I solve the problem

Comment: @RRM I'm here to help.  I am glad I helped you.  I could use the points , I'm so close to 5 ,000.  If you gave me an up vote or the green check, that would help me.